# Unable to pass a parameter from one pipeline job to another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parameter-passing

Editing the question: I am trying to run a simple pipeline job which triggers another pipeline job and sends parameter values.
I tried a simplified usecase in the example below

Piepeline - Parent

```
pipeline{
agent any
options {
    buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')
}
stages {
    stage('Invoke sample_pipleline') {
        steps {
                CommitID = 'e2b6cdf1e8018560b3ba51cbf253de4f33647b5a'
                Branch = "master"
            input id: 'Environment', message: 'Approval', parameters: [choice(choices: ['FRST', 'QA', 'PROD'], description: '', name: 'depServer')], submitter: 'FCMIS-SFTP-LBAAS', submitterParameter: 'user'
            build job: 'simple_child', 
        parameters: [string(name: 'CommitID', value: 'e2b6cdf1e8018560b3ba51cbf253de4f33647b5a'),string(name: 'Environment', value: depServer), string(name: 'Branch', value: 'master')], 
                quietPeriod: 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

Pipeline - child

```
pipeline{
agent any
parameters {
    string defaultValue: '', description: 'K', name: 'depServer'
}
options {
    buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')
}
stages {
    stage('CodePull') {
        steps {
            echo "Testing"
            echo "${depServer}"
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the parent pipeline it did not trigger child pipeline but gave error.

```
    Started by user ARAV
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on Windows_aubale in                 C:\Users\arav\Documents\Proj\Automation\Jenkins\Jenkins_slave_root_directory\workspace\sample_parent2
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Invoke sample_pipleline)
    [Pipeline] input
    Input requested
    Approved by ARAV
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: depServer for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

After implementing changes suggested and with some tweaks The parent job triggers the child job but the child log shows that it doesn't receive the parameter passed.

```
    Started by upstream project "sample_parent" build number 46
    originally caused by:
    Started by user ARAV
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple_child
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (CodePull)
    [Pipeline] echo
    Testing
    [Pipeline] echo

    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong here.
Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child pipeline has parameter named "depServer":

```
parameters {
    string name: 'depServer', defaultValue: '', description: ''
}
```

You should provide a value for it:

```
build job: 'simple_child', 
    parameters: [string(name: 'depServer', value: 'SOMETHING']
```

Finally, you should address it:

```
        steps {
            echo "Testing"
            echo "${params.depServer}"
        }
```

Comment: parameters: [string(name: 'depServer', value: 'SOMETHING')]

Comment: missing the closing ')'

Answer (score 1):

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: depServer for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding

This means that you don't have defined a variable `depServer`.

Fix it by assigning the result of the `input` step to variable `depServer`:

```
steps {
    script {
        def input_env = input id: 'Environment', message: 'Approval', parameters: [choice(choices: ['FRST', 'QA', 'PROD'], description: '', name: 'depServer')], submitter: 'FCMIS-SFTP-LBAAS', submitterParameter: 'user'

        build job: 'simple_child', 
            parameters: [string(name: 'CommitID', value: 'aa21a592d1039cbce043e5cefea421efeb5446a5'),string(name: 'Environment', value: input_env.depServer), string(name: 'Branch', value: "master")], 
            quietPeriod: 1
    }
}
```

I've added a `script` block, to be able to create and assign a variable.

The `input` actually returns a `HashMap` that looks like this:

```
[depServer:QA, user:someUser]
```

That's why we have to write `input_env.depServer` as argument for the build job.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Zett. However it gave me an error
org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String

Comment: However I got it t work as follows

`script{
                   def depServer
                userip = input id: 'Environment', message: 'Approval', parameters: [choice(choices: ['FRST', 'QA', 'PROD'], description: '', name: 'input_env')], submitter: 'FCMIS-SFTP-LBAAS', submitterParameter: 'user'
depServer = userip.input_env
echo "depServer"
                build job: 'simple_child', parameters: [string(name: 'CommitID', value: "12376"),string(name: 'Environment', value: depServer), string(name: 'Branch', value: ''master')], quietPeriod: 1
                }`

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the new issue as the parameter value is not passed to the child job

Comment: @Arpit It was my fault. The `input` step actually returns a `HashMap` in your case. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @Arpit Please revert your edit as it makes this QA hard to follow for future readers. My answer no longer matches your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much zett42 and MaratC! So finally the code that worked is as follows(combining both the answers):

Parent script:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Invoke sample_pipleline') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def CommitID
                    def depServer
                    def Branch
                    CommitID = 'e2b6cdf1e8018560b3ba51cbf253de4f33647b5a'
                    Branch = "master"
                userip = input id: 'Environment', message: 'Approval', parameters: [choice(choices: ['FRST', 'QA', 'PROD'], description: '', name: 'input_env')], submitter: 'FCMIS-SFTP-LBAAS', submitterParameter: 'user'
                depServer = userip.input_env
                echo "${depServer}"
                build job: 'simple_child', 
            parameters: [string(name: 'CommitID', value: "${CommitID}"),
                         string(name: 'Environment', value: "${depServer}"), 
                         string(name: 'Branch', value: "${Branch}")], 
                    quietPeriod: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child script:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    parameters {
        string defaultValue: '', description: 'K', name: 'Environment'
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('CodePull') {
            steps {
                echo "Testing"
                echo "${params.Environment}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not accept the answer that helped you? Did none of the answers help you, so you had to post your own one?

Comment: Both the answers helped me. But I couldn't select both.Neither do i intend to claim credit for this answer. Since it had two inherent issues, I posted one answer showing code that finally worked solving both issues for simplicity for future readers. If this is not the correct way i can delete my answer

Comment: I am not a judge. I am simply a helpful neighbour. It doesn't look good when you post the same solution as your own answer instead of accepting or upvoting, but if no single answer helped you then I guess posting a complete answer of your own works too.